# Inject Angular service with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having to create an app using Angular 1.5 and TypeScript. I am extremely new to TypeScript and trying to inject a service into the controller.

Currently getting `Cannot find name 'AppService'`

Controller :

```
class HomeController {
    static $inject = ['AppService'];
    private apps: Object[];    

    constructor(AppService: AppService) {
        AppService
            .getApps()
            .success((apps) => this.apps);
    }
}

export default HomeController;
```

index file :

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import HomeComponent from './home.component';
import {AppService} from '../../services/app.service';

const home =  angular
    .module('main.app.home', [])
    .component('home', HomeComponent)
    .service('AppService', AppService)
    .config(($stateProvider) => {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<home></home>'
            });
    })
    .name;

export default home;
```

service.modules :

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import {AppService} from './app.service';

const services = angular
    .module('main.app.services', [])
    .service('AppService', AppService)
    .name;

export default services;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I import the service in the controller I can access it no problem...but when I try to inject it in, I get that error. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it a compile-time problem or a runtime problem? What is the complete and exact error message/stacktrace? How do you bootstrap your application? Why is AppService defined in two different modules?

Comment: @JBNizet It gives the warning at compile time and it just points to the home controller. It should not be defined twice, I agree. But how can I inject the service in the controller by using it defined in the services.module

Comment: By making sure that the module which contains the controller has a dependency on the module which contains the service. It seems you just forgot `import {AppService} from './app.service'` in the controller, hence the error.

Comment: @JBNizet if I import the service in the controller it works fine. It should not have to be included in there. I should be able to use `$inject` to pull it in.

Comment: As soon as you use a type in a file, this type has to be imported. That has nothing to do with injection. Importing the type allows TypeScript to know which type you're using, which methods are available on that type and on instances of that type, etc. at **compile-time** You **are** injecting the service in the controller, and injection happens at **runtime**. You **wouldn't** be injecting it if you used `new AppService()` to get a reference to an **instance** of AppService. BTW, your variable should be named `appService`, not `AppService`.

Comment: @JBNizet ah okay. I understand. So is the service.module file unnecessary?

Comment: It's unnecessary if you want the service to be in the `main.app.home` module, and if you don't want to have a `main.app.services` module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121557/discussion-between-erichardson30-and-jb-nizet).